# Google Sheets Script to Only Send Email Only When Column A in the Active Row is Edited

Tags: google-sheets

I've done a lot of searching on this, but I can't find exactly what I need.  What I'm trying to do is the following:

I have a Google Spreadsheet and Column A contains a drop down of specific values (statuses).  When the value is set to "Completed" then I want an email to send.

I have the send email portion working however if it is set to "Completed" already and I go to change something else in the row then it sends another email.  I can statically specify a column (e.g.; A11) in the IF statement, but it needs to be dynamic for each active row in column A.

Here is my code so far.  Thanks in advance.

```
function EmailOnCompletion(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var row = s.getActiveRange().getRow();

  var status = s.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
  var hostname = s.getRange(row, 7).getValue();
  var to = s.getRange(row, 5).getValue();
  var subject = 'subject';
  var html = 'body';

  if( status == 'Completed') {
      GmailApp.sendEmail(to, subject, html, {htmlBody: html, from: "email@address.com"});
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already passing an event object with the onEdit trigger that you can use.
Using that is also safer as there may be a delay and the currently active cell may have changed.

If the status cell is in column A just use

```
if (e.value === "Completed" && e.range.getColumn() === 1)
```

to check if the status column of that row has been changed to `"Completed"`.

You can also use the event object to infer the recipient to stay consistent.